# Receber contagem em tempo real de um programa

Tags: php

É possivel fazer um programa .exe, que tivesse um temporizador de 60 segundos, e a cada segundo que passa enviaria informações para uma página php e essa página php mostrava a mudança de segundos em tempo real consoante o programa?

Se for possível, como poderia fazer isto?

Obrigado.

Comment: Sim, porem tem que levar em conta o tempo de atraso na comunicação(internet), pode ser que esse "tempo real", não seja tão real ... heheheh. Dependendo da linguagem ou ferramenta que você utilizar para gerar o ".exe" é até bem simples enviar uma requisição para um servidor PHP. Porem, no PHP, o meio mais simples(talvez o único, não sei...) é colocar esse valor no banco de dados, e fazer com que as outras "conexões" fiquem constantemente verificando por essa alteração. O que, provavelmente causaria mais atraso.

Comment: a dúvida é sobre como fazer o tal programa .exe ou é sobre php?

Comment: Basicamente é o que o usel5978 está a dizer.

Comment: É sobre PHP e exe

Answer (score 1):

É possível.

O seguinte código C# pode ser compilado para um arquivo `.exe`, e faz: para sempre (1), espera sessenta segundos (2), faz uma requisição numa página PHP (3) e pega o que a página imprimir para processar (4).

```
    public static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        int dados = 0;
        while ( true ) // 1
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep( TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 60 ) ); // 2
            dados++;
            using ( var client = new System.Net.WebClient() )
            {
                var retorno = client.DownloadString( "http://servidor.url/pagina.php?dado=" + dados ); // 3
                Console.WriteLine( retorno ); // 4
            }
        }
    }
```

É preciso baixar uma IDE de programação C# ou o equivalente em outra linguagem.

Também é possível fazer [um .exe de um PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046675/convert-a-php-script-into-a-stand-alone-windows-executable), mas não é uma solução tão comum.

Comment: Esse código C#, é possivel que envie o valor a cada segundo que passa para essa pagina.php via get?

Comment: Sim. Basta trocar o `TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 60 )` por `TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 1 )`. Teria de mexer no código para ser exatamente um segundo entre as chamadas, mas isso envolveria controle de threads, que parece ser um pouco além da sua questão original.